# What is the difference between process.exit() vs return when ending the process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, out-of-memory

I wrote a code that ends the process under certain conditions, and when I write it as a `return`, it ends abnormally due to an **over-memory error**, and `process.exit()` ends normally.

*P.S. My code is just only one function. So the two method quit the one  function.*

Can you explain the difference between the two methods when ending the process?

```
if(condition === true)
    process.exit();
```

```
if(condition === true)
    return;
```

Comment: I suspect the problem isn't with `return`, it's with the code *around* it. If you do something like recursive calls, then a `return` might not stop all the executions.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for your comment. But there's only 1 function and 1 for loop in the function. The two methods just terminate the for loop. There's no other codes after the for loop.

Comment: Without a proper [mcve] it's impossible to say what the difference is. The fact remains that `return` will exit the current function, `process.exit()` terminates all execution. If `return` doesn't terminate everything then *something* else is happening which `process.exit()` prevents. So, the difference is still in all the other code.

Comment: @VLAZ I understand. I think there's *something else* that ```return``` cannot prevent. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Explicitly calling `process.exit` forcibly discards some pending asynchronous tasks.

> Calling process.exit() will force the process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending that have not yet completed fully, including I/O operations to process.stdout and process.stderr.

-- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

2. `process.exit()` prevents the `beforeExit` event from emitting.

> The 'beforeExit' event is emitted when Node.js empties its event loop and has no additional work to schedule. Normally, the Node.js process will exit when there is no work scheduled, but a listener registered on the 'beforeExit' event can make asynchronous calls, and thereby cause the Node.js process to continue.

-- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit

Answer (score 5):

return will only stop the function that contains the return statement.
process.exit will stop all the running functions and stop all the tasks.

So when you call return it will stop the current function but execute the remaining functions.

Comment: Thanks. But there's no remaning codes after this condition. The two methods do the same thing.

Comment: @hyojoon It's obvious that you still have some event handlers listening to events. One way to avoid `process.exit` is to make sure you close all database connections, file streams, setInterval etc. Once the last event handler is removed the process will automatically exit. One way to avoid figuring out what event handlers are still open and close them one by one is to call `process.exit()`